# Protect html/php files with password

Tags: php, security

I have PHP files which I would like to protect. I want that only the server/browser will be able to read them, but if someone tries to open them with some text-editor, it will ask for password or something like that.

Is it possible doing such a thing?

If not, please supply me some ways which I can guard my files from being opened and viewed.

Comment: use htpasswd for this

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.. what OS?  are you expecting them to be accessing them over the internet, or from within the OS itself?

Comment: @msturdy From the PC which the files are located on. It's a web application, but it's working LOCALY using WAMP.

Comment: @HarishSingh I have barely any knowledge on what you've just stated. Could you please provide more information, perhaps a link?

Comment: You want to set the file permissions.. Google is a good place to start your search: https://www.google.com/search?q=wamp+file+permissions

Answer (score 2):

in your ".htaccess" :

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthUserFile /home1/c/clifford/public_html/protected/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

1. Change the path after "AuthUserFile" to the location of where your
   .htpasswd file will be (should be in the same directory as
   .htaccess).
2. You can simply change "c" to the first letter of your
   PennKey, "clifford" to your full PennKey, and "protected" to the
   directory you want to protect.
3. Save the file and upload it to the directory you want to protect using your favorite FTP client

Manual here
http://www.seas.upenn.edu/cets/answers/auth-htpasswd.html

you can generate the file with following link
http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/password/#.UpdLhuKBa_I

Comment: I'm not sure you've understood me correctly. I'm trying to protect a file that isn't stored on a webhost, I would like let the server access it whenever it wants. I don't want that a human being will open up the file. When someone double-click the file on the PC which the file is stored on(working LOCALY ONLY) it will ask for password

Comment: which type of files you have

Comment: I have PHP files which I'd like to protect

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to protect is your files being accessed from the same PC, you should isolate the files using a special profile.

Since you are using WAMP i'll assume you are using Windows.

So my suggestion is that you create a user (with a password) to run WAMP, and that access to his folder is only allowed for him and by the Administrator. Of course you also should set up a strong password for your Administrator account.

This way you don't only allow the access to your PHP files but also to the WAMP config files and the running instance which could expose interesting information for an intruder.

None the less you should also check your webapp security, but that's another story.